# What's the difference between background field and dynamical gauge field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, field-theory

Dynamical gauge fields are assumed to be able to respond to sources.

What's the difference in the *Lagrangians* between a background field and  a dynamical field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, in the path integral formalism

$$ Z~=~\int \!{\cal D}\phi~ \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S[\phi]\right), $$

the dynamical$^1$ quantum field variables

$$\phi^{\alpha}(x)~=~B^{\alpha}(x)+\eta^{\alpha}(x)$$

are split into two parts:

1. a classical background field configuration $B^{\alpha}(x)$, which satisfies the classical equations$^2$ of motion (with classical background sources$^3$ $J_{\alpha}(x)$),
2. and a quantum fluctuation part $\eta^{\alpha}(x)$, which is (perturbatively) integrated over in the path integral
   $$ Z[B]~=~\int \!{\cal D}\eta~ \exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}S[B+\eta]\right), $$

See also e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_field_method) Wikipedia page.

--

$^1$ The word *dynamical* will here for simplicity just mean that the field variable is an integration variable in the path integral. (Often the word *dynamical* is only used for propagating fields (as opposed to an non-propagating auxiliary field, e.g. Lagrange multipliers and ghosts)). In contrast, the word *background* is typically assigned to variables that are *not* integrated over in the path integral.

$^2$ We assume for simplicity that there (with the given boundary conditions and the given classical sources) is a unique classical solution for $B^{\alpha}(x)$, i.e. we ignore [instantons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instantons) here.

$^3$ The classical source configuration $J_{\alpha}(x)$ should typically satisfy certain consistency conditions, such as, e.g., a [continuity equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation).